# R - Selecting control group days days close to observation times

Tags: r, date, validation, subset, lubridate

I have a set of many different kind of observations that contain the Date of observations on special days (sam1, sam2, sam3). My aim is now to perform a wilcox.test() to find out if there is a significant difference between the observations on these special days and not special days. So I need to find a method to find suitable days to use as a control group. I want to try out at least 3 different control groups. The special days are very different, some represent a whole season, some only rainy days, some only cold days, some stormy weather. So they can be spread over the whole 2 years, some might only occur in one single month.

```
Start <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
End <- as.Date("2017-12-31")
all_dates <- seq(from = Start, to = End, by = 1)

set.seed(1)
sam1<- sample(dates, 30)
sam2<- sample(dates, 5)
sam3<- sample(dates, 120)
```

all_dates represents my observation period. sam1-3 contain the days of different observations. What I want to do now is to find:

1. The closest days to my important observations (same number of days that are in the sample)
2. Random days in roughly the same time the important observations took place (also same number of days as in the sample). It must not be the closest days, but roughly around the same time like in the same months or only 1 before/later.
3. Any days (I know how to do that, no help needed there)

My idea was to cut out the days of important observations from my whole observation period and then apply a routine that selects my control group days. That is where I stuck now. Any ideas?

Comment: Must define properly your search task: Are the "closest" days equally closer if they are the previous or the next day? how to choose in that case?. What is the measure of "roughly the same time? around 5-10 days?, days in the same range of the observations? around the same mean date of the samples?

Comment: It doesnt matter if it is before or after. Can be decided randomly. And with roughly the same time I mean in the same month. If that is not possible, than just the previous or following 1-2 months. Same mean date will not always work since I will get then a control group that is in only 1 season. The spread over the year should be the same than in my observation group. I think request number 1 is clear? Its only about the 2nd request.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking about it again. It would be better to always chose the closest day BEFORE in my first request.